# PHP Google insert calendar event API

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am using this package : https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

```
$google_service = new Google_Service_Calendar($google_client);
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(....));
// Insert Calendar event
$event = $google_service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
p($event);
$meet_link = $event->conferenceData->entryPoints[0]->uri;
```

I used to get `$meet_link` like this from the API but suddenly it started throwing error

```
trying to get property 'entryPoints' of non-object"
```

Infact calendar event has been inserted perfectly but I am not getting `$event->conferenceData->entryPoints[0]->uri` in response. Infact I am not getting this entryPoints `object($event->conferenceData->entryPoints)`

Comment: in fact as the error mentiones you are not getting the conferenceData which is, AFAIK not a required key. There might not be a conference on the event

Comment: Did you try patching the event with the additional data?  did you try doing an event.get with fields = * to ensure that you are getting all of the response data back?

Comment: Yes When I print_r($event). There is no "entryPoints"  key anywhere in the whole object. But calendar meeting inserted properly only the issue with response doesnt contain that google meet link which I require to save in database.

Comment: Many people facing the same issue. I think its from google API side.
Reference : https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/167260246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/167260246) with the conferenceData returned when creating an event with the API.

You can click on the star next to the issue number to receive updates and to give more priority to the report.

Comment: Thanks Its seems like the given link has same issue as I have.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution. Request part needs to change.

For the PHP API

I passed conference Data in request

```
$event = [ 
    .......,
    "conferenceData" => [
            "createRequest" => [
                 "conferenceSolutionKey" => [
                    "type" => "hangoutsMeet"
                 ],
                "requestId" => "123"
            ]
    ]
];
$google_service->events->insert($calendarId, $event,['conferenceDataVersion' => 1]);
```

and passed 3rd parameter as settings ['conferenceDataVersion' => 1] Then its
returning meeting link so its working now.